# Assistance downloading UR interface for Ros2 humble

Tags: ros2, robotic-arm, c++, ros-humble

Im getting an error for downloading the ur robot driver. its a line inside a c++ file causing the issue, i cant find the right command to use. Heres the error, please help!

```
/home/morgan/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_robot_driver/src/hardware_interface.cpp: In member function ‘virtual hardware_interface::CallbackReturn ur_robot_driver::URPositionHardwareInterface::on_activate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State&)’:
/home/morgan/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_robot_driver/src/hardware_interface.cpp:432:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘uint32_t’ {aka ‘unsigned int’} [-fpermissive]
  432 |     ur_driver_->setKeepaliveCount("keep_alive_count");
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                   |
      |                                   const char*
In file included from /home/morgan/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_robot_driver/include/ur_robot_driver/hardware_interface.hpp:55,
                 from /home/morgan/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_robot_driver/src/hardware_interface.cpp:50:
/opt/ros/humble/include/ur_client_library/ur/ur_driver.h:461:36: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void urcl::UrDriver::setKeepaliveCount(uint32_t)’
  461 |   setKeepaliveCount(const uint32_t count);
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/home/morgan/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_robot_driver/src/hardware_interface.cpp:432:34: warning: ‘void urcl::UrDriver::setKeepaliveCount(uint32_t)’ is deprecated: Set keepaliveCount is deprecated, instead set the robot receive timeout directly in the write commands. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  432 |     ur_driver_->setKeepaliveCount("keep_alive_count");
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/morgan/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_robot_driver/include/ur_robot_driver/hardware_interface.hpp:55,
                 from /home/morgan/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_robot_driver/src/hardware_interface.cpp:50:
/opt/ros/humble/include/ur_client_library/ur/ur_driver.h:461:3: note: declared here
  461 |   setKeepaliveCount(const uint32_t count);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ur_robot_driver_plugin.dir/build.make:90: CMakeFiles/ur_robot_driver_plugin.dir/src/hardware_interface.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:148: CMakeFiles/ur_robot_driver_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< ur_robot_driver [4.52s, exited with code 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not the latest version of humble branch.

The error message indicates that the input is a `const char*`, but if you look at [this latest code](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/blob/humble/ur_robot_driver/src/hardware_interface.cpp#L432), it is a `const int` variable defined in line 418.

Download the latest version from [Gitchub](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/tree/humble) should be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: That worked for the line 418, thank you! but for line 432, even with the latest github, the setkeepalivecount still is wrong, I still cant find the correct command for it

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about why it is still wrong? With the latest change, I assume the data type is now `const int` right?